# Custom Azure B2C Password Reset Flow via Username

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I setup a password reset flow using Azure B2C and local Azure accounts that uses the user's email address and verification code.  However, my client would like to have a password reset email sent to the user based on the user name, not email address.  The user email would be looked-up behind the scenes and an email sent that would include a link to the password reset page as shown in the flow below.

After reading a gazillion articles on custom Azure B2C policies, I'm struggling to convince myself if it is possible to do what the client is asking for using Azure B2C.

In the sample password reset flow shown below, some of the areas I'm struggling with include:

- Is it possible to create custom pages in the password reset flow such as the page in Step 4 that displays the user's masked email address, or the information page in Step 7?
- Is there built-in functionality to look-up a user's email address and Active Directory Object ID based on their user name or would I have to call out to a custom Azure Function and use the Graph API to do this?
- Is it possible to create and send a custom email that includes a hyperlink to the password reset page that includes the user's Active Directory Object ID as a query string parameter so the password reset page knows which user's password is being reset?

At the moment, it seems like it would be easier to create a completely custom ASP.NET MVC app to handle the requirements than it would be to use Azure B2C custom policies, but that isn't really a path I want to go down.

[image]

Comment: If my answer helpful You can mark it by clicking on checkbox beside your question. So it would be helpful for other . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is it possible to create custom pages in the password reset flow?

> Yes you can create your own custom password reset [user flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies) using [azure active
>   directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-password-change-custom)
>
> In your case if you want to figure out your custom page you could
>   refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui)

- Is there built-in functionality to look-up a user's email address and
  Active Directory Object ID based on their user name or would I have
  to call out to a custom Azure Function and use the Graph API to do
  this?

> Using [Microsoft Graph REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?toc=./toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) you could fetch your user
>   information.
>          In your case you could use
>
> - *[List users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)*
> - *[Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0)*
>
>   To access user information you could also refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0) in a great
>     details

- Is it possible to create and send a custom email that includes a
  hyperlink to the password reset page that includes the user's Active
  Directory Object ID as a query string parameter so the password reset
  page knows which user's password is being reset?

> You can use the [company branding feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding) to customize the
>   content of verification     emails for resetting password.
>
> **Note :**      For better clarity you could check the Azure AD B2C: [Frequently asked 
>               questions (FAQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs) before final work around Which definitely guide you to 
>               define ultimate go ahead.

**Update**

[image]

As per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions) right now you cannot create according to your sample exactly. See the screen shot there is and important remarks.

Thank you.

Comment: @PoorInRichfield check out your way around. If you have any more query feel free to ask here in comments. Thank you.

Comment: I understand the Graph API functionality and have already "branded" the existing Azure B2C pages for my client.   However, I see no way to create a page in a user flow that doesn't already exist... All I can do is brand or customize the look of existing pages (as far as I can tell).  I see no way to create a "Message Sent" page (Step 4) that takes a dynamic string as input and has a button that closes the window.

Comment: @PoorInRichfield I have updated my answer according to Microsoft documentation. In production level you cannot create your own customized user flow page as they don't allow it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Now I'm wondering if we should've chosen Auth0 or Okta over B2C.

Comment: @PoorInRichfield If you don't have any specific obligation I would  prefer Auth() because of its popularity and feature. Azure has big support on auth protocol though its also very popular among the software engineers now a days of its friendly implemtation . Here is some of comparison https://comparisons.financesonline.com/auth0-vs-okta-identity-cloud

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub project covers the case you describe. Still needs a lot of understanding about custom flows to get it working.
https://github.com/yoelhor/aadb2c-verification-link